# Three-way xor-like function

Tags: function, operators, xor

I'm trying to solve the following puzzle:

`Given a stream of numbers (only 1 iteration over them is allowed) in which all numbers appear 3 times, but 1 number appear only 2 times, find this number, using O(1) memory.`

I started with the idea that, if all numbers appeared 2 times, and 1 number only once, I could use `xor` operation between all numbers and the result would be the incognito number.

So I want to extend this idea to solve the puzzle. All I need is a xor-like function (or operator), which would yield 0 on the third apply:

`SEED xor3 X xor3 X xor3 X = SEED`

`X xor3 Y xor3 SEED xor3 X xor3 Y xor3 Y xor3 X = SEED`

Any ideas for such a function?

Comment: +1: cute question. In attempting to prove that "there does not exist such a function", I stumbled on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regard XOR as summation on each bit of a number expressed in binary (i.e. a radix of 2), modulo 2.

Now consider a numerical system consisting of *tribits* 0, 1, and 2. That is, it has a radix of 3.

The operator `T` now becomes an operation on any number, decomposed into this radix. As in XOR, you sum the bits, but the difference is that operator `T` is ran in modulo 3.

You can easily show that `a T a T a` is zero for any `a`. You can also show that `T` is both commutative and associative. That is necessary since, in general, your sequence will have the numbers jumbled up.

Now apply this to your list of numbers. At the end of the operation, the output will be `b` where `b = o T o` and `o` is the number that occurs exactly twice.

Comment: Why do you say it is difficult?

Comment: Converting a number to base 3 efficiently may give you headaches. Perhaps I'll remove that sentence though.

Comment: From an implementational point of view I would just hold a digit array, it would anyway satisfy the o(1) memory requirement.

Comment: OK. It would be nice to see the solution once you have it ;-)

Comment: I am curious if there are other solutions to this, anyways, this works perfectly.

Comment: @Bathsheba The final result in this case is 'b'. How do you get the 'o' out of the result which is what the question is asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution for the simpler case (all number appear twice, one number appears once) works since *xor* operates on each bit x as

```
x xor x = 0 and 0 xor x = x
```

xor is basically a bit-wise summation modulus 2. You would need the base-3 equivalent: Transform each number into a base-3 representation. And then use summation modulus 3 for each decimal:

```
     0  1  2

0    0  1  2
1    1  2  0
2    2  0  1
```

Call this operation xor3. Now you have for each decimal x:

```
x xor3 x xor3 x = 0 and 0 xor3 x = x
```

If you apply that to all your numbers then all values that appear 3 times will vanish. The result is x xor3 x of the number x that appears twice. You need to apply decimal-wise division by 2 modulus 3.

I believe there are more efficient ways to implement that. The advantage of the xor function in the first case relies on the fact that xor is a natural base-2 operation. Is there any practical application for that?

Comment: If the final result is "x xor3 x", how do you get the 'x' value out of the result?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is a bit fragile: If the precondition (all numbers appear 3 times except one that appears twice) breaks the algorithm will not help you.

Take a Map with int-keys and int-values. Then walk through your numbers and for each number x increase each the according value. If x is a new key take 0 as start value.

Then you can analyze it easily: Walk through all keys and check the cardinality. It should be three for all keys except one that should be two. This is more robust and my gut feeling says it is also faster.