# Given an array of integers, where every number appears thrice except one number appears twice, find the number that appears twice?

Tags: arrays, duplicates, operators, bitwise-operators, xor

This is a problem from "Elements of programming interview". I saw this problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887820/three-way-xor-like-function) but the accepted answer (or other answers) are not complete.

Using an XOR like operation that works on base 3 systems (which is called `xor3` in the post), you get the result which is `x xor3 x`. However, the problem is to get `x`. `xor3` is defined as addition modulo 3 (where numbers are represented in base 3 system)

How do we get the `x` portion out of `x xor3 x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you go through the array of numbers once again? Lets say the value that you have after the first iteration is `a = x xor3 x`

Iterate through all the entries in the array, and `xor3` each value with `a`.

```
for y in arr:
    if y xor3 a == 0:
        print y
        break
    else
        continue
```

For now I think this is the naive solution. This is still O(n) considering each `xor3` as O(1) with O(1) memory.